# Schema.org and Person's logo instead of image/photo

Tags: microdata

I want to mark up someone's website with Microdata, so I was going to use her name and logo using schema.org's [Person](http://schema.org/Person) vocabulary.

However, there is no such a thing I could use for her logo type. She doesn't have (or want) a picture on the website, so I will use her logo instead.

Is the `itemprop="photo"` appropriate for this case? I found this "photo" thing [here](http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Person/) but it is not defined on `schema.org`.

Comment: It may not be clear from PatomaS's answer below, but you wouldn't want to mix `Data-Vocabulary.org` markup with `schema.org` markup, if that's what you thinking of doing. Seems the `image` property would be the right choice since people often use avatars to identify themselves online (like on this site), which is like a personal logo.

Comment: @dan Thanks for clearing it out, it wasn't so clear. Btw, it feel that `Data-Vocabulary.org` exists now only for "encyclopedic knowledge" as their main website seems suggest using `schema.org`, right?

Comment: No problem. Most are using `schema.org` markup now since it's a collaboration between Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo, which are the major search engine players. See [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158?hl=en&ref_topic=1088472) for more about that.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough and thanks @dan for helping to make this answer better.

Comment: No problem, just helping to improve and already good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being strict while keeping things simple, and without mixing vocabularies, you can use the [image](http://schema.org/image) property, which is generic but specific enough about the content you are marking up.

A logo is not normally associated with a person, it's associated with a product, a company, or things like that. So for practical purposes, the image she uses is going to define her.

If for some reason you really want to go with the idea of the logo, then you can use [logo from Brand](http://schema.org/Brand). But this may be seen as stretching the concept a bit.

Of course we don't know if she is popular/recognized enough to be associated with a company. Maybe in a small circle she is, and that is all you need to be technically correct.

Finally, you can choose to be not so technically correct and use what people would interpret easier.

Comment: Even though I think this is a good answer, I 'm still trying to decide. Let's say, you (not a famous person, are you? :p ) are a web-designer and you don't want to put your photo, but your logo instead. What would you do?

Comment: I would use image